# Проблема с отображением в IE

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Вот мой код

```css
.n_user {
    background: url(http://guides.gosuslugi.ru/download.html?file=/765/1.svg&dl=0) no-repeat scroll left center;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn-user" href="users/login/" title="Личный кабинет"><span class="n_user">Войти</span></a>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить проблему отображения в IE

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось все проще.

```
<a class="btn-user" href="users/login/" title="Личный кабинет"><span class="n_user"></span>Войти</a>
```

Достал "Войти" из спана.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй не через bg у спана, а через ::after сделать.

```
.n_user::after{
content:"";
background: url(http://guides.gosuslugi.ru/download.html?file=/765/1.svg&dl=0) no-repeat scroll left center;
position:absolute;
left:-10px;
top:0;
}
.n_user{
position: relative;
}
```

Ну и таким макаром поставь иконку как тебе удобно.

Answer (score 0):

.n_user {
    background: url(http://guides.gosuslugi.ru/download.html?file=/765/1.svg&dl=0) no-repeat left center;
    background-size:2%;
    display:block;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

Comment: размер подбери background-size:?%;